# How to add and retrieve rows elements from List in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am using Entityframework and in my application i have defined a class in which i have set some properties and their values.As there is a Step wise process so i have declared that class as List now i need to add rows or properties values at each step.

```
    //i have declared class as list like below 
    List<ProcessSteps> objSteps = new List<ProcessSteps>(); 

   // for step 1 
    ProcessSteps obj = new ProcessSteps();
    obj.id= 1;
    obj.name= "v2k";
    obj.Step=1;
    objSteps.Add(obj);

    // for step 2
    ProcessSteps obj = new ProcessSteps();
    obj.id= 2;
    obj.name= "vvk";
    obj.Step=2;
    objSteps.Add(obj);
```

So at some point i need to access both id 1 and 2 but i'm nnot able to get by objSteps because each time objSteps overwrite previous one. and on debugging shows me count as 1.

Comment: for each step there is a postback..

Comment: So that means you are initializing objSteps it in every step...

Comment: why does adding a new values to list<> over write previous values in the list

Comment: @CodingDefined no  objSteps in initializd once but i am initializing obj on each step

Comment: because for each step there is a postback, page will be loaded again and objSteps will be initialized again. And when you add it again since new objSteps does not have any value it will add and show you 1.

Comment: this code is on page load?

Comment: but i have initialized it on first time page load not for postback..still ??

Comment: public partial class Products : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    List<ProcessSteps> objSteps = new List<ProcessSteps>();
} i have declared as above

Comment: @CodingDefined i have declred objSteps at class level as above comment then why it is overwritten

Comment: You have to check if its first time load or its because of postback using !Page.IsPostBack or you can check if objSteps is null then initialize otherwise dont do anything...

Comment: do you want these ProcessSteps to be stored in DB ?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider an asp.net page life cycle, every time your application gets a request it would recreate a new instance of your class (code behind) so it doesn't matter if you have a field on class level, it would be redefined with each request.

so what can you do to preserve your `state`?

there is [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) and [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in asp.net webforms which you can use.

In your case maybe something like this:

```
public List<ProcessSteps> Steps 
{
    get
    {
        if(ViewState["ProcessSteps"] == null)
            ViewState["ProcessSteps"] = new List<ProcessSteps>();
        return (List<ProcessSteps>)ViewState["ProcessSteps"];
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["ProcessSteps"] = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially your logic will give error like

`A local variable named 'obj' is already defined in this scope`.

So try to change your instance name.I just create one console application based on your logic like

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ProcessSteps> objSteps = new List<ProcessSteps>();

        // for step 1 
        ProcessSteps obj = new ProcessSteps();
        obj.id = 1;
        obj.name = "v2k";
        obj.Step = 1;
        objSteps.Add(obj);

        // for step 2
        ProcessSteps obj2 = new ProcessSteps();
        obj2.id = 2;
        obj2.name = "vvk";
        obj2.Step = 2;
        objSteps.Add(obj2);
        foreach (var item in objSteps)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.name);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

and it works fine.